# Conversion from weighted cyclic to acyclic graph

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph, cyclic-graph

How to convert a given weighted cyclic graph among n nodes to a acyclic graph with minimum sum of edges? With an added information that in the output graph each node wont have more than D incoming edges. Weights are positive

Comment: Wow, yeah, 3000 rep required to migrate.  Well, since there are no answers or votes, you can always just delete this question and re-open it on cs.sx.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55661/755).  See there for comments on improving your question.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may delete your question and repost it on the other site, or click 'flag' to flag for moderator attention and request migration.

Comment: 1. I can't understand what you are asking.  What is the input?  What is the output?  What relationship do you want them to have?  What if I output a trivial graph with just one vertex?  Presumably you won't be happy with that; but why not?  What requirement does that violate?  What is meant by "with minimum sum of edges"?  Please edit the question to specify the problem statement more clearly.  2. What have you tried?  What approaches have you considered?  See http://stackoverflow/help/how-to-ask and then edit the question based on the advice there.  Thank you!

Comment: @alexw, for future reference, if you recommend another site, it'd be helpful to remind the individual not to cross-post, as that is prohibited by site rules.  Thanks for explaining how to delete and re-post.  Also, it'd be better to avoid recommending other sites if you're not active there and already familiar with their standards.  This question is not a good fit for CS.SE in its current form; it doesn't show any indication of what skn2 has tried, and it's hard to tell what the question is asking.  Thank you for listening!

Comment: In its current form, no.  I figured CS.SE would give OP some encouragement to improve their question - and it seems that you have!  I am quite aware that other SE websites are considerably less lax than SO in enforcing their quality guidelines.